# WebStorm Linking to a .js file in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, linker, webstorm

HTML and CSS are working fine, but I cannot get Webstorm to link and use my .js file.

I have live edit working. In the debugger console it reads:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:3 script.js:3
```

I am guessing the "3" is referencing the three $ in the .js file.

In Webstorm settings, I have jQuery-2.0.0 enabled globally. I've tried jquery-1.7.1 and I still have the same problem.

There are three files involved. I am including them all to give as a complete picture as possible. They are all in the same project file. Here is my code -

webpage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>For Testing</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                Random text
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

stylesheet.css:

```
div {
    height: 18px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").onmouseover(function(){
      $("div").css("background-color", "green")
   });
});
```

I am guessing there is a simple newbie solution, but I am new to programming and Webstorm is a bit overwhelming. I did check the site for solutions but was unable to find an answer that worked.

Comment: @Andy G: You may want to consider reverting this question to its original name on grounds that it was a Webstorm specific issue.

Comment: I've reinstated it on your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Your HTML to reflect these changes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>For Testing</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <!--Add this line below which will add the jquery library-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                Random text
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I do this, the source address highlights. When I mouse over the highlight, it says "There is no locally stored library for the http link". I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:1 script.js:1

Comment: -"There is no locally stored library for the http link": hit Alt+Enter and choose 'download library' to gen the file downloaded and configured as a javascript library (to get highlighting/completion working)

Comment: @lena & apfunk: Alt+enter worked, but I do not understand why Webstorm didn't detect the libraries that came prepackaged or the 1.10.2.min.js library I stored locally, even though it was automatically added to the Webstorm project directory tree when I dropped it in the same Webstorm project file on my computer. If anyone can explain that to me, it would be helpful so that I am not just resolving the issue but I and others who find this helpful in the future know **why**. I am very thankful for the help, and look forward to a time when I am knowledgable enough to help others!

Comment: what do you mean saying that it doesn't detect it? The warning shown in your html file? The warning just means that no local file is associated with this URL - and this association is only created when you download a library. If you do already have the corresponding .js file in your project directory, you can just ignore this warning or turn it off (Settings/Inspections/JavaScript/General/There is no locally stored library...). This inspection just helps you to set up your libraries - you can either use it or ignore if you prefer downloading and configuring libraries manually

Answer (score 1):

No idea what 'Webstorm' is, but your HTML contains no reference to the jQuery library. This is where `$` is defined.

At the following above your existing `<script>` tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="[ PATH TO JQUERY ]"></script>
```

Comment: Just to add to that, "$(document)" looks like it's using jquery. If adding your 'Webstorm' js library doesn't fix it, try adding jquery's. i.e. <script type="text/javascript" src="_http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: I tried downloading jquery-1.10.2.min.js, and stored the text file in the same folder as the HTML document. Webstorm instantly added it to my directory in the Webstorm with the same name, so Webstorm understands what it is. I wrote the path to jQuery as src=jquery-1.10.2.min.js with no autocorrect errors detected, but in the console debugger it gives me the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'onmouseover' script.js:2
   script.js:2
  c jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
  p.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
  x.extend.ready jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4
  q jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4

Comment: ----- and I should add that this is the error I get when I write it above the already written text. When I write it below, I get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined script.js:1
   script.js:1

Answer (score 0):

1. try using `mouseover` instead of `onmouseover`:

   $(document).ready(function(){
          $("div").mouseover(function(){
             $("div").css("background-color", "green")
          });
       });
2. add a link to jquery to your HTML (see the first answer)